# Semantic UI React Transition not animating

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am trying to animate entry & exit of a React Class based component using React Semantic UI's **[Transition](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/transition/)**. But it's not working. See https://codesandbox.io/s/k23z06o43r?fontsize=14.

In the snippet, I have 3 experiments going:

1. Use Transition to animate entry and exit of a Class Component - Does
   not work
2. Same as above but the Class component is wrapped in a div
   within the Transition - Works as expected, but I don't want the div,
   if possible. Or at least understand why its necessary.
3. Same as 1) with unMount prop set for the Transition. - Does not animate the
   entry/exit, but mounts/unMounts the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PackageComponent` should spread unhandled props and merge styles:

```
class PackageComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      /* Spread below is important */
      <Container {...this.props} style={{ ...styleObj, ...this.props.style }}> 
        {this.props.children}
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Updated CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/8zk6v6wzw8

Answer (score 5):

Well, I myself never used this library, but it seems like the semantic-ui does not work properly with custome components inside of the transition component. You could use the Container component from semantic-ui and then simply pass in your custome component as a child, that works.